# Simulate drain current gate voltage for QDFET

Tags: software

I've modeled a QDFET transistor of sorts at an atomic scale, as it's not a standard MOSFET, and was wondering how to do a drain current/gate voltage simulation. I don't really have any idea how to begin with this, and was wondering anyone had any guidance. Thank you!

More specifically, I was trying to simulate the results of [this](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-18932-5) paper, however simulation of transistors beyond the standard FET model is fairly limited from what my google searches tell me.

In addition, I asked the authors of above paper, and they listed to read [this](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-86790-2) paper of theirs.

Comment: Interesting question, I can't help you but perhaps you can help others looking at your question by providing a bit more information (e.g. references etc).

Comment: Made edits, although I don't know how much that will really improve.

Comment: It's just that it's not clear what you want. Asking for general guidance is way too broad of a question. What is it about that paper that you don't understand? Perhaps if you put down more information you can understand it better and then ask a more specific question where you get stuck.